# 3ds при загрузке в three.js загружается без текстур

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax

Есть модель 3D max но при загрузке в three.js все загружается без текстур, кто то может подсказать как сконвертировать или сохранить в 3D max чтобы правильно работало с текстурами

Comment: форматы есть в .fbx и в .max  также в  Unity пробовал пересохранить не помогло

Comment: Вот, поддерживаемые форматы на любой вкус: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=loader

Comment: fbx поддерживается вроде но выводит без текстур, просто черные контуры модели

Comment: а источник света в сцене есть?

Comment: да есть, HemisphereLight  и PointLight

Comment: можно задать этот вопрос на [форуме](https://discourse.threejs.org/), приложив модель в формате `.bfx`, а еще лучше привести живой пример с проблемой.

Comment: да наверно так и сделаю, проект только на локалке, если получится в codepen поставить файлы или загрузить на сервер